# Solr Search Failing on Certain Characters

Tags: solr

I have a Solr collection that's not returning results for a few non-ASCII characters. The example we are using is the string `S11. • “≡ «Ñaïvétý» ‘¢¥£’ ¶!#%`; searching for that whole string returns no results even though I have an object with that in an indexed field. However, searching for substrings of that string does return matches. The only characters that cause Solr to return no matches are three in the middle: `• “≡`. The field was indexed as `text_en` but I have also tried `edge_ngram` (hoping for a bit of Cargo Cult magic to fix the problem). Is there something special about these three characters or do I need to tweak how Solr indexes the fields?

We are searching via django-haystack but the problem shows up in the Solr admin as well.

Here are the two field type definitions:

```xml
<fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"        
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" 
            catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" 
            minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" 
            catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you check if the blanks are really blanks? There are several characters that look like blanks, but are not. One example is the "[Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)". These may become garbled up when copy and pasting.

Comment: Last question :) how are the fieldTypes `text_en` and `edge_ngram` defined in your schema? Would you share them? Then we could try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cheffe - added the field definitions. I was wondering about the whitespace characters as well but as far as I can tell they are just normal space characters. Solr has no problem splitting the query into "words" on those spaces just like the other spaces when I look at the query in the admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory)

> Converts alphabetic, numeric, and symbolic Unicode characters which
>   are not in the first 127 ASCII characters (the "Basic Latin" Unicode
>   block) into their ASCII equivalents, if one exists.

```
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ...

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Please have a look at the analysis page ...is this what you expect?

Comment: I honestly don't know enough to know what I'm looking at. The `EdgeNGraFilterFactory` items seem to be splitting it properly and the query doesn't look mangled. Are you seeing a match? I can't tell from the image.

Comment: I had "• “≡" in the query and it shows in the result ..Its been highlighted in the tool with different color.

Comment: If you try the fieldType added above...I think your issue will get resolved...I have added the screenshot of the analysis page where it show the text match which is expected by you...

Comment: The field type above throws [an exception](https://gist.github.com/tclancy/332d5dced531fffbacfb). Relevant part seems to be: `Side.BACK is not supported anymore as of Lucene 4.4, use ReverseStringFilter up-front and afterward`. Even after altering the definition per [this link](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/03/prefix-and-suffix-matches-in-solr.html) I do not get a match.

Comment: oh...yes its been removed ..I used solr 3.3 version where it is available...Did you tried with ReverseStringFilter?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried both fieldTypes you have posted and checked them on the analysis page that ships with the Solr admin page. Both appear to be OK - have a look below. The light shades of grey indicate that a match is produced.

This leaves me a bit puzzled. There a several reasons though why you do not get a hit:

- you have changed the schema.xml **without** rebuilding the index, this will operate, but generate not hits
- you are using the dismax/edismax queryhandler with the MM parameter defined with a unfavourable value.

  - You can look this up in your solrconfig.xml
  - However this is just the default value, the parameter may be altered when sending the request from your code.
- you have interesting values in the three files that are involved during indexing, namely

  - lang/stopwords_en.txt
  - protwords.txt
  - synonyms.txt

**Results for text_en**
[image]

**Results for edge_ngram**
[image]

Comment: I have been rebuilding with each changes (at least I hope so). I don't see `dismax` or `edismax` in our conf XML but how would I check if this is the problem? As for the last, even taking the synonyms and stop words out of the field definition doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please check the `<requestHandler ...>` you have in your solrconfig.xml those define which handler you are using. At best, add that to your question. You may check the [Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) or the [Solr Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig) for what to look for.

Comment: There isn't a requestHandler block.

Comment: OK, could you share how you create the query/share the query parameters? As you are likely using the default, you probably query a different field than you think. What is the `defaultSerachField` in your schema? In case you have one.